# Bind params for the bulk INSERT query? (avoid SQL injections)

Tags: performance, yii, sql-injection, bulkinsert

I want to do some mass DB population from Excel file.
The most time economic way is to use `INSERT INTO` statement with lots of values to be stored in one transaction:

```
INSERT INTO `assortment`(`id`, `sku`, `agroup`, `subgroup`, `title`, `measure_unit`, `price`, `discount`, `imageUrl`, `fileUrl`) 
VALUES ([value-1],[value-2],[value-3],[value-4],[value-5],[value-6],[value-7],[value-8],[value-9],[value-10]), 
([value-1],[value-2],[value-3],[value-4],[value-5],[value-6],[value-7],[value-8],[value-9],[value-10]), 
([value-1],[value-2],[value-3],[value-4],[value-5],[value-6],[value-7],[value-8],[value-9],[value-10]), 
([value-1],[value-2],[value-3],[value-4],[value-5],[value-6],[value-7],[value-8],[value-9],[value-10]), 
...
```

Yet, to avoid SQL injection i wish to bind params, the yii providing [functionality](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.dao#binding-parameters) for that. Yet, it seems impossible for me to do it for hundredes/thousands of values. Isn't it?

To keep SQL hygene i did the simple insert thru Active Record attributes (Yii AR functionality sanitizes input data by default):

```
$auxarr = array();
for ($i = 0; $sheetData[$i]; $i++) 
{
        $model = new Assortment();
        $j = 0; 
            foreach ($labels as $label)
            {
                $auxarr[$label] = $sheetData[$i][$j++];
            }
        $model->attributes = $auxarr;
        if (!$model->save()) 
            throw new CHttpException(400, 'Error db storing');
}
```

This approach obviously being time non-efficient.
**Is there any way that would feature both security and time efficiency in the bulk SQL inserting?**

Comment: i prefer to insert 1 by 1. It's more time efficient, but there are some factors which doesnt allow me to use bulk: big table with indexes, continous record(reading) to db and so on. Anyway i doubt (or don't know) how to make it  and possible it or no.

Comment: Define "time non-efficient". In certain numbers please.

Comment: can't you use [load data](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html)?

Comment: i've no time efficiency metrics for these transactions (even excel load fails to now), the only reason i apply is the theoretical knowledge of the DB functioning: **1 transaction against multiple ones**.

Comment: 1 transaction against multiple once sometimes way faster.

Comment: @ineersa Define "way faster". In certain numbers please.

Comment: Bulk insert - 1000 records on 30gb table with indexes takes about 3 minutes, 1by1 takes about 20 seconds. 2nd - on bulk table locked, on 1by1 doesnt.

Comment: @Adler, as far as [load data](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html), this "statement reads rows from a text file into a table at a very high speed", yet, (1) i see no way how to apply parameters and (2) not sure it'll fit the Yii structure.

Comment: it can be done in command line, but loading not trusted files with load data not recommended i think, and again indexes can crush you, if you use bulk insert or load data - your table must be inactive, otherwise will be very bad. Insert itself very fast, but indexes will start to refresh with your imported data, so it will take some time (here why 1by1 preferable on working table), and during this time table will be locked. If you have incoming queries into it - you'll have big troubles.

Comment: Thank you, ineersa, for detailed consulting. Incoming queries are not a problem in this case, but the indexing new records is truly slowes/should slow bulk insert.

Answer (score 1):

Yii is using conventional PDO in CDbCommand.
So, you can create a string consists of series values like this

```
(?,?,?),(?,?,?),(?,?,?),(?,?,?),(?,?,?),(?,?,?)
```

then create an array with values for all these placeholders
and finally execute all the stuff

Comment: i'll try to apply it.

Answer (score 1):

My approach is

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `assortment`(`id`, `sku`, `agroup`, `subgroup`, `title`, `measure_unit`, `price`, `discount`, `imageUrl`, `fileUrl`) VALUES "

$params = array();
$cntRows = count($sheetData);
for ($i = 0; $i < $cntRows; $i++) 
{

    $j = 0;         
    $rowParams = array();
    foreach ($labels as $label)
    {
        $rowParams[":{$label}_{$i}_{j}"] = $sheetData[$i][$j++];


    }
    $params = array_merge($params, $rowParams);
    $sql . = "(" . implode(",", array_keys($rowParams) ) .")"

}
/*
 Sql now is : INSERT INTO assortment (....) VALUES (  :id_1_1 , sku_1_1 , ... )  (:id_2_1 , sku_2_1 , ...)
 AND $params is { :id_1_1 => [value]  ........ }
*/

$cmd = Yii::app()->db->createCommand($sql);
$cmd->execute($params);
```

We excute insert sql in one transaction, no multiple transactions or use ActiveRecord (waste memory and many functions are executed) and avoid SQL injections. If your data is large you can split it to multiple transactions.